# JsonConvert failing to deserialize?

Tags: c#

Issue with deserializing sample JSON to object with C#. I'm expecting the two integers in HabitProgress to be assigned although they are both 0 (default value)?

Testing with:

```
var statusResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HabitStatusJsonResponse>(File.ReadAllText("/home/ash/dev/habit-response-test.json"));
Console.WriteLine(statusResponse.Data.Progress.CurrentValue); // always returns 0?
```

Models / classes:

```
public class HabitStatus
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public HabitProgress Progress { get; set; }
}

public class HabitProgress
{
    [JsonPropertyName("current_value")]
    public int CurrentValue { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("target_value")]
    public int TargetValue { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "errors": [],
  "message": "Success",
  "data": {
    "status": "completed",
    "progress": {
      "current_value": 63.386128135522206,
      "target_value": 60,
      "unit_type": "min",
      "periodicity": "daily",
      "reference_date": "2023-09-02T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  "version": "v1.2",
  "status": true
}
```

Comment: Ah and the correct attribute is `[JsonProperty]`, the one used here is for System.Text.Json

Comment: Your class structure doesn't match the document format.

Answer (score 2):

Output: 63.386128135522206

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var statusResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HabitStatusJsonResponse>(""" 
            {
              "errors": [],
              "message": "Success",
              "data": {
                "status": "completed",
                "progress": {
                  "current_value": 63.386128135522206,
                  "target_value": 60,
                  "unit_type": "min",
                  "periodicity": "daily",
                  "reference_date": "2023-09-02T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
              },
              "version": "v1.2",
              "status": true
            }
        """);
        Console.WriteLine(statusResponse.Data.Progress.CurrentValue);
    }
}

public class HabitStatusJsonResponse
{
    public List<object> Errors { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public HabitStatus Data { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

public class HabitStatus
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public HabitProgress Progress { get; set; }
}

public class HabitProgress
{
    [JsonProperty("current_value")]
    public double CurrentValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("target_value")]
    public long TargetValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit_type")]
    public string UnitType { get; set; }

    public string Periodicity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reference_date")]
    public DateTimeOffset ReferenceDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's different?

Comment: You used the `JsonPropertyName` attribute, which is for the JSON serializer/deserializer from `System.Text.Json`. But then you're using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, which is from the Json.NET library. You can't mix and match.